# while unit testing on rails i get "NameError: undefined local variable or method" for the path - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

this is the unit test  i have written  as project_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProjectTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "projects" do
    visit new_project_path
    click_link "new_Project"
    fill_in "Title", :with => "test app"
    fill_in "Project_type", :with => "basic"
    fill_date "Date_fielded" , :with => "2012/12/3"
    fill_in "Owner name", :with => "chetan"
    fill_in "Status", :with => "new"
    fill_in "Brand", :with => "nike"
    click_link "Create_Project"            
 end
end
```

i get this as error

```
1) Error:
test_projects(ProjectTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_projects_path' for #<ProjectTest:0xaa6a25c>
test/unit/project_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ProjectTest>'
```

i have tried changing the path to check for the error in path  but that didnt work 
 and  also checked the rake routes to check the path

Answer (score 1):

That should be `new_project_path`, i.e. `project` should be singular and not plural. See the Rails Routing docs section on [Paths and URLs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls) for details.

Comment: yes  sir  but still that didnt work    test_projects(ProjectTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_project_path' for #<ProjectTest:0x9fb8020>
    test/unit/project_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ProjectTest>'

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see a dump of

```
rake routes
```

but I would suspect that that the link name is wrong and should be

```
new_project_path
```

instead of

```
new_projects_path
```

Also, if you are using RESTful routes you more than likely do not have the new_Project link on the new_project_path page, it is more likely on the index (projects_path) but rake routes would help narrow that down.

Comment: yes sir  i have corrected and tried it but that too didnt work            test_projects(ProjectTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_project_path' for #<ProjectTest:0x9fb8020>
    test/unit/project_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:ProjectTest>'

Comment: Could you add a dump of rake routes to the question?

Comment: projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                             projects#index
               POST   /projects(.:format)                                             projects#create
                                         new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                                         projects#new
                                        edit_project GET    /projects/:id       /edit(.:format)                                    projects#editproject GET    /projects:id(.:format)                                         projects#show

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass from `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` to write an integration test (and `ActionController::TestCase` for a controller functional test).

`ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` has things like url helpers setup for you.

Comment: How do you subclass both?

Comment: You can't - pick one.